# We hav enabled Activity History for SysAdm & have shared access to other users through permission set but Event&task are not visible to other users

Tags: activities

Activity Setting is enabled for all user but Event and Task related list is visible only to System Admin and not to other users. Have checked the system permission for other user still it is not visible.

Comment: Please use only relevant tags; this is not related to `community` or `salesforcedx`.

Comment: Have you placed the appropriate Related List or Lightning component on your page?